# Dynamically added elements don't load in my jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, slider, jslider, document-ready

My page currently uses [Slides](http://www.slidesjs.com)

I want to be able to add new "slides" to my slider dynamically.  The way I do this is through an XML document, which contains a link to the "slide image" and the href.

My jQuery code to dynamically add elements is this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/slider_non_flash_images.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        jQuery(xml).find('image').each(function() {
            var imagesrc = jQuery(this).find('src').text();
            var url = jQuery(this).find('href').text();
            var item = '<div><a href="' + url + '"><img src="' + imagesrc + '"/></a></div>';
            jQuery('.slides_container').append(item);
        });
    }
});
```

This all works, and adds the divs to the slides containing div.  The problem is, the slide doesn't work.

If I hard code the `<div>` elements within the container myself, they load just fine.

Could this be a "timing" issue?  Where the elements are loaded after the slider attemps to run?  And if so, how can I add them prior to.  This all happens in the `(document).ready` method.  Is there something sooner?

Thanks.

I'm sure someone will ask, so here's the code to start the slider.

```
jQuery('#slides').slides({
    preload: true,
    preloadImage: 'images/loader.gif',
    play: 8000,
    effect: 'fade',
    pause: 15250000,
    slideSpeed: 8000,
    crossfade: true,
    fadeEasing: "easeOutQuad",
    hoverPause: true
});
```

Comment: you may need to have it reload the DOM using the `.live()` function it will not see elements that are not there when the page is first `ready()` so you need to tell is to look for them.

Comment: All you have to do to fix it is set the option `async:false` in your `.ajax` call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sliders scan the DOM for currently existing elements only onload. If the DOM is changed (i.e. dynamically with ajax), you may have to re-initialize the slider. How to do this will be different for each slider plugin.

You could try putting the $('#sliders').slides(...) call into a function, calling that function on pageload, then re-calling that function whenever the DOM is changed by ajax.

Comment: So, would I call that 'function' in my jQuery.ajax method?

Comment: Yes .. once on-load, within your "$(function(){...});", then again in your jQuery.ajax "success" callback.

Answer (score 1):

check out http://api.jquery.com/live for more details on the live function